# Is it possible to send command to console window in which my program is running?

Tags: c++, windows, console

I know the `system()` function but that creates it's own environment so every variable set here isn't forwarded to main console. I wonder is it possible to send command as it would be written by the user or as it would be executed by *.bat file ?

The reason I need this is that I look for a way to set env variable of parent CMD process. And yes I know that system doesn't want me to do it, but maybe there is a some workaround for that...

Idea is to create app that would set as a variable anything that is send to it via input pipe, like this:

```
echo Bob| setvar name
```

so then:

```
echo %name%
```

would produce `Bob`

The whole idea is to make easier setting a variable from any program output (I know how to do it with `for` command) with taking account of peculiarities with special batch characters like `^!%` since these are allowed in file names. It would make simpler many cmd scripts.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly run programs in the same console window as your program. That's the default behavior for [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425.aspx). MSDN has more details on [what happens between related processes sharing a console](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682528.aspx). You'll probably want to wait for the child process to terminate before continuing to run your own program.

However, that won't help with your real goal. The *window* where a program runs has absolutely nothing to do with the *environment variables* of any of its ancestor processes. You'll have to [look elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwindows%5D+change+environment+variables+of+parent+process) for a solution to your real problem.